# Nullable value in command file

Tags: symfony, null, doctrine, repository, getter

I'm actually working on a symfony project where i have to get into the DB all the taxis with some informations about them and make them write in a CSV file.

For this, i've create a CiblageCommand File :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use AppBundle\Entity\Taxi;
use AppBundle\Entity\StatutTaxi;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class CiblageCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->em = $em;
}

protected function configure()
{
    $this
        //the short description shown while running "php bin/console list"
        ->setDescription('cible les taxis')
        //commande
        ->setname('ciblage')//php bin/console ciblage
        //the full command descriptionn shown when running the command with
        //the "--help" option
        ->setHelp('Cette commande permet de cibler les taxis valides présents'
            .' dans la BDD et de leur générer un PDF conforme.')
        ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    $io->title("Lancement de la génération");

    $io->title("\nListage des taxis");
    $this->create();/*
    $io->title("\nCiblage terminé");

    $io->title("\nGénération des courriers");
    $this->generation();
    */
    $io->success("\nGénération terminée");
}

protected function create()
{
    $repository_taxi = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Taxi');
    $listTaxi = $repository_taxi->findAll();

    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();

    $handle = fopen('CSVTaxi', 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, ['IDENTIFIANT', 'RAISON SOCIALE', 'STATUT', 'ETAT'], ';');

    foreach ($listTaxi as $taxi)
    {   
        if($taxi == null){
            $listTaxi[$taxi] = "NULL" ;
        }
        fputcsv(
            $handle,
            [
                $taxi->getNumAm(),
                $taxi->getRaisonSociale(),
                $taxi->getStatutTaxi()->getLibelleStatut(),
                $taxi->getEtatTaxi()->getLibelleEtat()],
            ';'
        );
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo("nbr taxi : ".count($listTaxi)."\n");
}
}
```

However, when i tried to do a "*getStatutTaxi()*" the value return is null and i cant write on the file despite the *if* before.

there is the error my terminal gave me

```
[apl4e04@l11750300app2dev 10:23:23] [~/web/html/scot] $ php bin/console ciblage

Lancement de la génération
==========================


Listage des taxis
==================

10:17:16 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "ciblage". Message: "Call to a 
member function getLibelleStatut() on null" ["exception" => Error { …},"command" => 
"ciblage","message" => "Call to a member function getLibelleStatut() on null"]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member 
function getLibelleStatut() on null in 
/app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/src/AppBundle/Command/CiblageCommand.php:74
Stack trace:
#0 /app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/src/AppBundle/Command/CiblageCommand.php(44): 
AppBundle\Command\CiblageCommand->create()#1/app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/vendor/
symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(255): 
AppBundle\Command\CiblageCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), 
Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/
Component/Console/Application.php(987): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command- 
>run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), 
Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3/app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/vendor/symfony/symfony/
src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application 
 .php(86): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(AppBundl in 
/app/apl4e04/web/html/scot/src/AppBundle/Command/CiblageCommand.php on line 74
```

How can i fix this and make this work ?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Cordially,

Comment: Message: "Call to a member function getLibelleStatut() on null...
So you are expecting that $taxi is a valid Taxi entity but it is empty. And on a empty value you cant call a function. And now you are about to overwrite your whole array to the string "NULL". Remove that whole if statement.

Comment: @FrankB ok but, LibelleStatut isnt always empty, he CAN be empty but not always, so in case he is empty and he return NULL how can i do for make him write it in my CSV file ?

Comment: It is not about the LibelleStatut but about your $taxi that is null instead of an Taxi object

Comment: Did you overwrite the findAll() method in your Taxi repository? If yes update your question with this method.

Comment: i didn't do it, just used the method findAll create by symfony. So i do it, now there is a new error who's saying  " Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : i just add a ternary function at my '*getLibelleStatut()*' who resolve the probleme.

```
protected function create()
{
    $repository_taxi = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Taxi');
    $listTaxi = $repository_taxi->findAll();

   //$doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    //$em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();

    $handle = fopen('CSVTaxi.csv', 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, [' IDENTIFIANT', 'RAISON SOCIALE', 'STATUT', 'ETAT'], ';');

    foreach ($listTaxi as $taxi)
    {
        fputcsv(
            $handle,
            [
                $taxi->getNumAm(),
                $taxi->getRaisonSociale(),
                ($taxi->getStatutTaxi()==null)?"":$taxi->getStatutTaxi()->getLibelleStatut(),
                $taxi->getEtatTaxi()->getLibelleEtat()],
            ';'
        );
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo("nbr taxi : ".count($listTaxi)."\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this by checking the value instance before adding to the csv file.

```
$statusLibelleStatut = $taxi->getStatutTaxi() instance of StatutTaxi ? $taxi->getStatutTaxi()->getLibelleStatut() : '';
$etatLibelleEtat = $taxi->getEtatTaxi() instance of LibelleEtat ? $taxi->getEtatTaxi()->getLibelleEtat() : '';

fputcsv(
            $handle,
            [
                $taxi->getNumAm(),
                $taxi->getRaisonSociale(),
                $statusLibelleStatut,
                $etatLibelleEtat],
            ';'
        );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but if you do this, there is gonna be empty for all values of "LibelleStatut' i just want it to be empty when "LibelleStatut" return NULL.

Comment: This one will be empty only when when "LibelleStatut" return NULL

Comment: I just tried and in my csv file all the boxes are empty for "LibelleStatut" and "LibelleEtat"